# time_t and LONG_MAX: issues with ctime() and difftime()

Tags: c, time

I know that *time_t* is a long int on my system implementation. For the sake of experimenting, let's initialize it with *INT_MAX*. The data are displayed correctly, and running the code some second later decreases the counter accordingly.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>  
#include<time.h>
#include<limits.h>

int main(){
    /* Set the current and a very large time */
    time_t now;
    time(&now);
    time_t max = INT_MAX;

    /* Print them on screen. */
    printf("Last time: %s", ctime(&max));
    printf("\nCurrent time: %s", ctime(&now));

    /* Compute their difference */
    double remaining = difftime(max, now);
    printf("Remaining seconds (difftime): %lf\n", remaining);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is: when I replace *INT_MAX* with *LONG_MAX*, I obtain two apparently strange behaviors.

1. ctime(&max) returns a NULL. The reason might be that, if I remember correctly, the string is supposed to have maximum length 26, in this case exceeded. Am I right?
2. if I run the code some seconds later, the variable "*remaining*" is still the same, conversely to the *MAX_INT* case where it decreases second after second. How can I explain such a behavior? (these values are surely below DBL_MAX)

EDIT: sorry, I wrote "size_t" instead of "time_t" in my previous version, my mistake.

Comment: Do you really mean `time_t` rather than `size_t` (which is almost certainly an *unsigned* type)?

Comment: There is nothing typed `size_t` within the code you show.

Comment: Yes, I mean time_t, not size_t; my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *if I run the code some seconds later, the variable "remaining" is
>   still the same*

Assuming your platform uses the [IEEE 754 representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) for a `double` type, then that will have a precision of *approximately* 16 (decimal) digits. Your `(long) long int` type's `LONG_MAX` (if 64-bits) has a value (probably) of `9223372036854775807`, which is **19** digits - so you are losing precision when subtracting `now` from `max`, and the displayed result will appear the same. If you were to wait more than 1,000 seconds between runs, then you would most likely see a difference.

> *ctime(&max) returns a NULL*

See: [ctime returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6035000/10871073).

Answer (score 0):

Type `time_t` is intended for timestamps.
I don't see why you would want to put `LONG_MAX` in there. Chances are its value is too big to properly represent a time stamp the system can handle.
So it would make sense `ctime()` doesn't know how to handle it and returns NULL to indicate the error.

About the question why `remaining` has the same value when reunning again later, I don't really know, unless `ctime(&max)` somehow alters the value of `max`.

Comment: I set it to LONG_MAX with no practical application in mind, rather it was an exercise.